# What is ‘Atika Kadisha’?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, shemos-sacred-names, zohar

In פתיחת אליהו it mentions the עתיקא קדישא, which literally means the Ancient Holy One. Is that a name of HaShem or referring to something else?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, a ספר by the name of Re’uyot Yehezkel identifies it as מטטרון. Not sure how reliable that is

Comment: Do you have the exact quote in the Sefer? IIRC עתיקא קדישא as used in Zemiros refers to an aspect of Shabbos, not of Hashem, but I can’t post that as an answer until I confirm the context is the same in פתחת אליהו.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95 Can you give a reference if not?

Comment: Patach Eliahu is a passage of tinune hazohar. The tetm atika kadisha is a reference for hashem in the sfirot topic.

Comment: I suggest learning the sefer Choker u'Mekubal from the sefer Shaarei Ramchal and then the sefer Klach Pischei Chochma קל"ח פתחי חכמה both from the Ramchal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is discussed in [Sefer Eitz Chaim, Heichal Shlishi (Heichal HaKeterim), Sha'ar Rishon (Sha'arei Atik)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14183&st=&pgnum=198).

Atikah Kadisha together with Arich Anpin is the highest level of existence in terms of the hishtalshelut of the universe. (They correspond to the individual aspects of maleness and femaleness and their union to be truly one.) As the Ari z"l explains, they are both included in *Keter of Atzilut*. It is not a name of HaShem, but above the level of names.

At this level of creation, the language of the Torah as transmitted by the Ari z"l is talking about paradigms for existence (what is called Shechinah in other places), meaning how we relate to or perceive G-d. In the language of Chassidut, this is usually delineated as the distinction between *Atzmut*, the framework of existence (In terms of allegory, think like the bones of the skeleton are the framework upon which the body is built. This is what we relate to.), and *Mahut*,  G-d as He truly is (which is beyond  the ability of all created beings to perceive at all).

This concept of *Atzmut* has an external aspect and an internal aspect just like our bones have an external, hard, white covering and an inner, soft, red marrow, which is the distinction between Arich Anpin and Atikah Kadisha.

Another important concept to understand about עתיקא קדישא is that it is from the root עתק which has a connotation of *copying* or *translating*.

In other words, עתיקא קדישא is introducing the paradigm of *Safrut* (Scribal Arts) and the *Faithful Sofer* (the Holy Scribe). In this usage, *Holy* has the connotation of copying without error. Whatever is being copied is a faithful copy of the original. But at the same time, it is a translation from the original into our native language. This corresponds to the many laws associated with the copying of a Sefer Torah (that it must be a perfect copy down to the letter or it is invalid) and also to the idea mentioned in [Noam Elimelech](https://www.sefaria.org/Noam_Elimelech%2C_Sefer_Vayikra%2C_Metzora.2.1?vhe=_Noam_Elimelech,_Lvov,_1788.&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and many other places, that:

> וזהו ידוע דאורייתא וקב"ה כולא חד

That G-d and the Torah are one.

And this idea, that creation is a reliable translation of G-d's oneness is in keeping with the text many recite on Erev Shabbat known as *Patach Eliyahu* (Eliyahu *the Prophet* opened and said...) which  describes the entire concept of the sephirot and states:

> **אַנְתְּ הוּא חַכִּים וְלָא בְּחָכְמָה יְדִיעָא. אַנְתְּ הוּא מֵבִין וְלָא בְּבִינָה יְדִיעָא.** לֵית לָךְ אֲתַר יְדִיעָא. **אֶלָּא לְאִשְׁתְּמוֹדְעָא תּוּקְפָךְ וְחֵילָךְ לִבְנֵי נָשָׁא** וּלְאַחֲזָאָה לוֹן אֵיךְ מִתְנַהֵג עָלְמָא בְּדִינָא וּבְרַחֲמֵי. דְּאִית צֶדֶק וּמִשְׁפָּט כְּפוּם עוֹבְדֵיהוֹן דִּבְנֵי נָשָׁא. דִּין אִיהוּ גְבוּרָא. מִשְׁפָּט עַמּוּדָא דְאֶמְצָעִיתָא. צֶדֶק מַלְכוּתָא קַדִּישָׁא, מֹאזְנֵי צֶדֶק תְּרֵין סַמְכֵי קְשׁוֹט, הִין צֶדֶק אוֹת בְּרִית קוֹדֶשׁ, כּוֹלָא לְאַחֲזָאָה אֵיךְ מִתְנַהֵג עָלְמָא, **אֲבָל לַאו דְּאִית לָךְ צֶדֶק יְדִיעָא** דְאִיהוּ דִין, **וְלָא מִשְׁפָּט יְדִיעָא** דְאִיהוּ רַחֲמֵי, **וְלָא מִכָּל אִלֵּין מִדּוֹת כְּלָל:**

That You, G-d, are *wise* but not with a *known wisdom*, etc.

That it uses different forms of the words for wisdom and understanding, etc. than are used for us, His creations. We, His creations, are, so to speak, a reliable copy of Him, who is truly one.

Answer (score 2):

Atika Kadisha is clearly defined in the Hashmatot of the Zohar at the end of Shemot, around page 275b.

There, we see that "Atik" refers God emphasizing God's transcendence from time and space. There are three ways this is done in the Kabbaah, as the Zohar there enumirates, Keter Chochma and Bina. That is, Keter- something totally unknowable, Chochma - the singular origin point of the universe, and Bina - the eternal guiding forces of the universe that are constant through time and space.

The Arizal's clam that Atik refers to Keter exclusively, and notions that it refers to Metatron are misguided.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Dr16 and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

It refers to עתיק יומין (which is the highest partzuf) as in the songs sung on shabbos אתקינו סעודתא. There too we find עתיק יומין being referred to as עתיקה קדישא (the ancient holy one).

Comment: Here is a quote from chabad.org “"Partzufim" are compound structures of the sefirot. A partzuf is a metaphorical figure of human likeness, used to represent the expansion of an individual sefira (or group of sefirot) into an independent configuration with ten sefirot of its own”.

Comment: As I’ve researched the topic a bit more, it seems that while sometimes עתיקא קדישא is used synonymously with עתיק יומין, other times it could be referring to a specific aspect of עתיק.

Comment: For r starters, I don’t think we are praying to
 atika kadisha, rather it is just stating that this 
Meal is the meal of atika kadisha (each meal
On shabbos corresponds to a different partzuf). 
Aside from that, I don’t believe there would be an 
Issue in praying to atika kadisha (at least from a 
Kabbalistic perspective) because it is an aspect 
Of G-d. In fact it seems from the sources I’ve seen
That atika kadisha is synonymous with the Ain Sof
Himself.

Comment: The Atika kadisha can’t be the אין סוף. According to one source, the עתיקא קדישא is מטטרון, so I’m pretty sure that might be עבודה זרה